# How to alter table to add new date time column that insert date time on each row creation?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I created a table now I want to add date time column but I want to current date time of each row insertion.

I have written syntax like this:
`ALTER TABLE particle_photon ADD COLUMN dt_created NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  AFTER  humidity;`

but I get error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  AFTER  humidity' at line 1
```

Comment: You forgot to define the data type.

Comment: You not set the Column type after dt_created. Insert TIMESTAMP after the Column name.

Comment: What version?  (Things have changed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the declaration of the datatype (I assume `TIMESTAMP`):

```
ALTER TABLE particle_photon 
ADD COLUMN dt_created TIMESTAMP
NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  AFTER humidity;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e24019b380992c038cc2961563b6888c)**:

```
CREATE TABLE particle_photon(id INT PRIMARY KEY, humidity INT, lastcol INT);

ALTER TABLE particle_photon 
ADD COLUMN dt_created TIMESTAMP
NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  AFTER humidity;
```